# Try catch in server side affect error handling in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling, react-redux

I'm working on a web app that works with node in server and react-redux in front-end.
The App is handling errors by redux in front-end and I want to use try-catch for the server because I want to keep my server working(sometimes because of one simple error server will be down).
But as try-catch is catching the error in the server after using try-catch in node (server) I'll not receive any message for that error in front-end( I have received a message related to error as I'm using redux)

My question is that: How can I handle my app to have error handling on both side? If I don't use try catch in the server, the server will be down. I want to have error-handling alongside in server and front-end.

For example, this is Update route in my app that I want to use try-catch, I have added this try-catch and now I can have the error in server console and in front-end by using a callback. But is it the correct way?

```
    app.put('/updateadmin', function(req, res, cb){

    var email =  req.body.email,
        // password = req.body.password,
        name = req.body.name;

    admin.updateAdmin(email, name, function(err, user){
        if (err)
            throw err;
        try {
            activity.insertActivity(user._id, 4, function(err){
                if (err)
                    throw err;
            });
        } catch (ex) {
            cb(ex);
            console.log(ex);
          }

    });

});
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you show at least your server code please ?

Comment: @JulienTASSIN I have added code

Comment: From my opinion, that is a correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this way to handle errors in express site:

```
app.put('/updateadmin', function(req, res, next){

var email =  req.body.email,
    name = req.body.name;

admin.updateAdmin(email, name, function(err, user){
    if (err)
        return next(err);

        activity.insertActivity(user._id, 4, function(err){
            if (err)
                return next(err);
        });

});

});
```

and in the top level of your app like App.js, you should handle errors.